# resource/aws_rds_cluster_instance is being destroyed and re-created when adding new resources in the tf file

Tags: amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

Terraform Version 1.4.6
AWS provider version 4.67.0

```js
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.67.0"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">=1.4.6"
}
```

RDS cluster/instance resources

```js
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "cluster" {
  cluster_identifier              = "aurora-cluster-demo"
  engine                          = "aurora-mysql"
  db_cluster_parameter_group_name = aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group.default.id
  db_subnet_group_name            = aws_db_subnet_group.database.name
  engine_version                  = "8.0.mysql_aurora.3.02.2"
  availability_zones              = [data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[0], data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[1]]
  database_name                   = "mydb"
  master_username                 = "foo"
  master_password                 = "A12dadf125"
  skip_final_snapshot             = true
  apply_immediately               = false
  enabled_cloudwatch_logs_exports = [
    "audit",
    "error",
    "general",
    "slowquery"
  ]
  serverlessv2_scaling_configuration {
    max_capacity = 1.0
    min_capacity = 0.5
  }
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [engine_version]
  }
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "cluster_instances_reader" {
  apply_immediately                     = false
  auto_minor_version_upgrade            = true
  availability_zone                     = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[1]
  ca_cert_identifier                    = "rds-ca-2019"
  cluster_identifier                    = aws_rds_cluster.cluster.id
  copy_tags_to_snapshot                 = false
  db_parameter_group_name               = aws_db_parameter_group.default.id
  db_subnet_group_name                  = aws_db_subnet_group.database.name
  engine                                = "aurora-mysql"
  engine_version                        = "8.0.mysql_aurora.3.02.2"
  identifier                            = "database-1-aurora-reader"
  identifier_prefix                     = null
  instance_class                        = "db.serverless"
  performance_insights_enabled          = true
  performance_insights_retention_period = 7
  promotion_tier                        = 1
  publicly_accessible                   = false
  tags                                  = {}
  tags_all                              = {}
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [engine_version]
  }
}
resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "cluster_instances_writer" {
  apply_immediately                     = false
  auto_minor_version_upgrade            = true
  availability_zone                     = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[0]
  ca_cert_identifier                    = "rds-ca-2019"
  cluster_identifier                    = aws_rds_cluster.cluster.id
  copy_tags_to_snapshot                 = false
  db_parameter_group_name               = aws_db_parameter_group.default.id
  db_subnet_group_name                  = aws_db_subnet_group.database.name
  engine                                = "aurora-mysql"
  engine_version                        = "8.0.mysql_aurora.3.02.2"
  identifier                            = "database-1-aurora-writer"
  identifier_prefix                     = null
  instance_class                        = "db.serverless"
  performance_insights_enabled          = true
  performance_insights_retention_period = 7
  promotion_tier                        = 1
  publicly_accessible                   = false
  tags                                  = {}
  tags_all                              = {}
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [engine_version]
  }
}
```

As apply_immediately is set to false, when applying the config with a version bump, there should be only update in-place actions for the both the cluster and the instances. This should put a pending modification for the cluster in AWS RDS, where the version update will be done during the next maintenance window.
Plan Output

```js
# aws_rds_cluster.cluster must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_rds_cluster" "cluster" {
      ~ allocated_storage                   = 1 -> (known after apply)
      ~ arn                                 =  -> (known after apply)
      ~ availability_zones                  = [ # forces replacement
          - "eu-west-1c",
            # (2 unchanged elements hidden)
        ]
      - backtrack_window                    = 0 -> null
      + cluster_identifier_prefix           = (known after apply)
      ~ cluster_members                     = [
          - "database-1-aurora-reader",
          - "database-1-aurora-writer",
        ] -> (known after apply)
      ~ cluster_resource_id                 = -> (known after apply)
      - deletion_protection                 = false -> null
      ~ endpoint                            =  -> (known after apply)
      ~ engine_version_actual               =-> (known after apply)
      ~ hosted_zone_id                      = -> (known after apply)
      - iam_database_authentication_enabled = false -> null
      ~ iam_roles                           = [] -> (known after apply)
      ~ id                                  = "aurora-cluster-demo" -> (known after apply)
      - iops                                = 0 -> null
      + kms_key_id                          = (known after apply)
      ~ master_user_secret                  = [] -> (known after apply)
      + master_user_secret_kms_key_id       = (known after apply)
      ~ network_type                        = "IPV4" -> (known after apply)
      ~ port                                = 3306 -> (known after apply)
      ~ preferred_backup_window             = "22:04-22:34" -> (known after apply)
      ~ preferred_maintenance_window        = "fri:03:03-fri:03:33" -> (known after apply)
      ~ reader_endpoint                     =  -> (known after apply)
      ~ storage_encrypted                   = false -> (known after apply)
      + storage_type                        = (known after apply)
      - tags                                = {} -> null
      ~ tags_all                            = {} -> (known after apply)
      ~ vpc_security_group_ids              = [
          - "sg-0ceeef054862e22e7",
        ] -> (known after apply)
        # (16 unchanged attributes hidden)

        # (1 unchanged block hidden)
    }

  # aws_rds_cluster_instance.cluster_instances_reader must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "cluster_instances_reader" {
      + apply_immediately                     = (known after apply)
      ~ arn                                   = -> (known after apply)
      ~ cluster_identifier                    =  -> (known after apply) # forces replacement
      ~ dbi_resource_id                       = -> (known after apply)
      ~ endpoint                              = -> (known after apply)
      ~ engine_version_actual                 = "8.0.mysql_aurora.3.02.2" -> (known after apply)
      ~ id                                    = "database-1-aurora-reader" -> (known after apply)
      + identifier_prefix                     = (known after apply)
      + kms_key_id                            = (known after apply)
      + monitoring_role_arn                   = (known after apply)
      ~ network_type                          = "IPV4" -> (known after apply)
      ~ performance_insights_kms_key_id       = -> (known after apply)
      ~ port                                  = 3306 -> (known after apply)
      ~ preferred_backup_window               = "22:04-22:34" -> (known after apply)
      ~ preferred_maintenance_window          = "mon:03:05-mon:03:35" -> (known after apply)
      ~ storage_encrypted                     = false -> (known after apply)
      - tags                                  = {} -> null
      ~ tags_all                              = {} -> (known after apply)
      ~ writer                                = false -> (known after apply)
        # (15 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }

  # aws_rds_cluster_instance.cluster_instances_writer must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "cluster_instances_writer" {
      + apply_immediately                     = (known after apply)
      ~ arn                                   = -> (known after apply)
      ~ cluster_identifier                    =-> (known after apply) # forces replacement
      ~ dbi_resource_id                       =  -> (known after apply)
      ~ endpoint                              =  -> (known after apply)
      ~ engine_version_actual                 = "8.0.mysql_aurora.3.02.2" -> (known after apply)
      ~ id                                    = "database-1-aurora-writer" -> (known after apply)
      + identifier_prefix                     = (known after apply)
      + kms_key_id                            = (known after apply)
      + monitoring_role_arn                   = (known after apply)
      ~ network_type                          = "IPV4" -> (known after apply)
      ~ performance_insights_kms_key_id       = -> (known after apply)
      ~ port                                  = 3306 -> (known after apply)
      ~ preferred_backup_window               = "22:04-22:34" -> (known after apply)
      ~ preferred_maintenance_window          = "thu:01:11-thu:01:41" -> (known after apply)
      ~ storage_encrypted                     = false -> (known after apply)
      - tags                                  = {} -> null
      ~ tags_all                              = {} -> (known after apply)
      ~ writer                                = true -> (known after apply)
        # (15 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }

  # aws_route_table.privateRT will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_route_table" "privateRT" {
        id               = "rtb-0538dfe8b9d7f73d8"
      ~ route            = [
          - {
              - carrier_gateway_id         = ""
              - cidr_block                 = "0.0.0.0/0"
              - core_network_arn           = ""
              - destination_prefix_list_id = ""
              - egress_only_gateway_id     = ""
              - gateway_id                 = ""
              - instance_id                = ""
              - ipv6_cidr_block            = ""
              - local_gateway_id           = ""
              - nat_gateway_id             = "nat-xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
              - network_interface_id       = ""
              - transit_gateway_id         = ""
              - vpc_endpoint_id            = ""
              - vpc_peering_connection_id  = ""
            },
          + {
              + carrier_gateway_id         = ""
              + cidr_block                 = "0.0.0.0/0"
              + core_network_arn           = ""
              + destination_prefix_list_id = ""
              + egress_only_gateway_id     = ""
              + gateway_id                 = "nat-xxxxxxxxxx"
              + instance_id                = ""
              + ipv6_cidr_block            = ""
              + local_gateway_id           = ""
              + nat_gateway_id             = ""
              + network_interface_id       = ""
              + transit_gateway_id         = ""
              + vpc_endpoint_id            = ""
              + vpc_peering_connection_id  = ""
            },
        ]
        tags             = {
            "Name" = "private-RT"
        }
        # (5 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }

  # aws_secretsmanager_secret.example will be created
  + resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "example" {
      + arn                            = (known after apply)
      + force_overwrite_replica_secret = false
      + id                             = (known after apply)
      + name                           = "aurora-rds-secret"
      + name_prefix                    = (known after apply)
      + policy                         = (known after apply)
      + recovery_window_in_days        = 30
      + rotation_enabled               = (known after apply)
      + rotation_lambda_arn            = (known after apply)
      + tags_all                       = (known after apply)
    }

Plan: 4 to add, 1 to change, 3 to destroy.
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is mentioned in the below link by justinretzolk.
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/31558